# OpenJPA: ConcurrentModificationException when finding an entity in a single threaded env

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I have three tables. Table A references to both table B and C with a composite FK.
When I simply do:

```
A a = (A) em.find(A.class, aPk);
```

It gives me ConcurrentModificationException.
Any pointer on what would go wrong?

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
private APK pk;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private B b;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private C c;
}

@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
private BPK pk;
...
}

@Entity
public class C implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
private CPK pk;
...
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:828)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ManagedCache.dirtyCheck(ManagedCache.java:307)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.hasTransactionalObjects(BrokerImpl.java:3820)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.addToTransaction(BrokerImpl.java:3892)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.setPCState(StateManagerImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.initialize(StateManagerImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.initialize(StateManagerImpl.java:275)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initializeState(JDBCStoreManager.java:351)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initialize(JDBCStoreManager.java:278)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.initialize(DelegatingStoreManager.java:111)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ROPStoreManager.initialize(ROPStoreManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:913)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:871)
```

Comment: What version of OpenJPA and how are you enhancing your Entities?

Comment: Have you implemented *hashCode()* and *equals()* of all entities correctly? Haven't you used ids anywhere in these methods?

Comment: OpenJPA 1.2.2. I didn't implement hashCode and equals. Do I need those?

Comment: It is also very strange that if the mappings are one-to-many or only one one-to-one mapping, then exception won't be there.

Comment: I found those generated hashCode() and equals() from the PK classes. What's with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the run time enhancer, most problems go away.